# How to use gDrive on Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook

How to use gDrive on Jupyter Notebooks?
I did try the method from the following link:

https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter-drive

But I am getting the following error when I run the command:

```
!python -m jupyterdrive
```

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'
```

And what needs to be done for this command? Where will log into google and where can we give access to the drive.

```
ipython notebook --profile <profilename>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing means that you do not have enough permission to write/read the `/usr/local/share/jupyter` location on your machine.

Try executing this as super-user to see if that works. If it does, this confirms that the problem is with permissions. Then you should move your code to somewhere where you have the permissions to execute it.

Comment: Can you give me code for using super user permission.